# Where can you find communities of chinese Esperanto speakers in the Internet?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

There are probably a lot of Chinese Esperanto speakers, but I don't remember the last time I wrote to one on the Internet. Chinese people are rare in websites/services such as Telegram, Reddit, Twitter and Facebook. Where should I go in order to find them? Do Esperanto communities exist in Chinese social media?

Answer (score 4):

You can try to ask about it at [Ĉina Esperanta Forumo](http://reto.cn/cgi-bin/forumo/forumo.cgi?id=cina-3), which seems quite active. I found it by entering [世界语](http://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&wd=%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E8%AF%AD) (the Chinese word for "Esperanto") into the Chinese search engine Baidu.